# Kubeflow error:Invalid input error: Job has no experiment. code:3 message

Tags: jobs, kubeflow, microk8s, kubeflow-pipelines

`    I am following tutorial of Kubeflow Pipelines API: [Kubeflow](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v1/tutorials/api-pipelines/) & [Kubeflow Pipelines API](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v1/reference/api/kubeflow-pipeline-api-spec/)

I've installed Kubeflow on a MicroK8s and started experimenting with the Kubeflow Pipelines API, I was able to upload a pipeline to the central dashboard by using [[kubeflow upload API](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v1/reference/api/kubeflow-pipeline-api-spec/)], but when      I tried utilizing the [Kubeflow RUN API](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v1/reference/api/kubeflow-pipeline-api-spec/#operation--apis-v1beta1-runs-post), I was unable to establish a RUN. As RUN_ID is showing as null but in the [document](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v1/tutorials/api-pipelines/),  by running this command curl ${SVC}/apis/v1beta1/runs/${RUN_ID} | jq it is showing the value of RUN_ID.Can anyone offer assistance.

I tried several various approaches, but they were unsuccessful, I was literally struck at my work regarding this issue can anyone please help on this issue..

```
RUN_ID=$((
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST ${SVC}/apis/v1beta1/runs
\-d @- \<\< EOF
{
"name":"${PIPELINE_NAME}\_run",
"pipeline_spec":{
"pipeline_id":"${PIPELINE_ID}"
}
}
EOF
) | jq -r .run.id)
```

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   388  100   277  100   111  23083   9250 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 32333
```

```
$ echo $RUN_ID
null
```

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST ${SVC}/apis/v1beta1/runs  
\-d @- \<\< EOF  
{  
"name":"${PIPELINE_NAME}\_run",
"pipeline_spec":{
"pipeline_id":"${PIPELINE_ID}"
}  
}  
EOF
{"error":"Invalid input error: Job has no experiment.","code":3,"message":"Invalid input error: Job has no experiment.","details":\[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/api.Error","error_message":"Job has no experiment.","error_details":"Invalid input error: Job has no experiment."}\]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it looks like you are trying to run the sequential pipeline from kubeflow usinf kiubeflow pipelines v1.
I would suggest once you have dowloaded the sequential.py file locally and compiled it using kfp SDK, it will give you a yaml or a tar.gz file. Use the GUI to upload the pipline using the yaml/tar.gz file and then create a run. Also check if the default experiment exists on your end, if not create an experiment and link your run with the same. If the default experiment exists, the setup should run.
I did the same on my side and it seems to be working fine.
Here is the snapshot of the successful run[image]

---

Can you share how did you configure your kubeflow pipeline? Every run of the pipeline is tied to an experiment so you will need to specify an experiment to tie the run to it. If you haven't create an experiment already, you can always create one as described [here for kubeflow pipelines v1](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v1/overview/quickstart/#run-a-basic-pipeline) or [here for kubeflow pipelines v2](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v2/run-a-pipeline/)

Comment: To build the pipeline, I'm using this guide [Building and running pipeline](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v1/tutorials/api-pipelines/). Additionally, I tried supplying the experiment ID, but it was unsuccessful. Would you kindly assist me with this?Please take a look at this as I've asked for it in Github.[Github link](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/9747).

Comment: Seems like you are using kubeflow piplines v1. Did you try v2?

Comment: Sorry Vikas,I didn't find any documnet, could you kindly share me link of creating the Experiment with the Kubeflow Pipelines API using V2?

Comment: you can install KFP2.0 using the instructions here https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v1/installation/standalone-deployment/#deploying-kubeflow-pipelines. This will give you a GUO which can ne used to create/upload your pipeline. I will update my original answer shortly if you can provide me the following details 1)how is your selup, are you doing it one of the clouds or locally on your laptop. 2) please provide source code for your pipeline as well perhaps a github link will do.

Comment: I've installed Kubeflow on MicroK8s, in my **Laptop** as I described above:[Microk8s URL](https://charmed-kubeflow.io/docs/install) also having access to Kubeflow dashboard. [Use this tutorial](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v1/tutorials/api-pipelines/) to Experiment with the Kubeflow Pipelines API. and I was utilizing the same [Github URL](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/sdk/release-1.8/samples/core/sequential/sequential.py) that was supplied in document I'm using for testing, but it's not functioning as indicated in the primary problem. can you please check.

Comment: I think something is wrong with your setup, as all runs go to the "default" experiment by default and the tutorial is also suggesting the same. Can yoy navaigate to the experiments tab in central dashboard and see if you can see the entry for default?

Comment: I just reproduced the issue on my side, and its working fine. I would suggest once yiou have generated the tar.gz file or yaml file, use the GUI to upload and submit the pipeline

Comment: @srikargoudjavvaji did you have any success with the UI?